# How to automatically timestamp org-mode TODO status other than DONE?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I notice that if you change the org-mode Todo Keywords list around, the last keyword on the list is interpreted as the DONE status for the purposes of the Todo Done customization. I would like to add a keyword ABANDONED and also record the timestamp when that status is toggled, but I don't see that in the customization. Is there a simple way to do it which won't make my .emacs file too crufty and cryptic, or an easy way to do it with customize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the vertical pipe ("|") character to separate the TODO states from the DONE states (include it in the list with your keywords as another regular item).

To enable insertion of the timestamp when triggering one of the DONE states, set the variable "org-log-done".

So, for your example, you could add this to your .emacs:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      (quote ((sequence "TODO(t)" "|" "ABANDONED(b)" "DONE(d)"))))
(setq org-log-done t)
```

(Notice this also sets the keyboard shortcuts for easy and quick setting of TODO states, with the "b" key used to set the ABANDONED state).

For further info on all these settings, examine them in Emacs (with C-h k, then just enter the name of the variable). Also the org-mode manual is a great resource:
[Org Mode manual - Workflow states](http://orgmode.org/manual/Workflow-states.html#Workflow-states)

Comment: Great! I can live with modifying this and leaving out the customize interface for this one setting.